# The webparts in my search site have stopped working

Tags: web-part, search, error, 2016, display-template

Currently we have a version of sharepoint 2016 on-premise. The search site use to work fine but then suddenly one day they cannot find the js file for the webpart. i have confirmed and the js files are located in the link in the error. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screen shot, something is very wrong. Your image links are broken too. It appears that the path to your publishing files is messed up. I would troubleshoot that.

Once the page is loading the default images and refinement I would then troubleshoot the rest  using your preferred tool, like F12.